# Opencart - Show the title of a module when it is added to a page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have a module named 'Deals of the Day'. After adding this module to some information page, the information page is having it's title but the module's title 'Deal of the Day' is not showing up. I want every module's title to be present when we add one or more modules to a page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which theme do you use?

Comment: Hi @kanenas, the theme is cosyone.

Comment: If you add "Deals of the Day" in "Category" does it display the title? Have you seen something in your error.log?

Comment: Also you may open a ticket here https://velikorodnov.ticksy.com/public-tickets/7147/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller:

```
$data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
```

In template:

```
<?php echo $heading_title ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Infated - Thanks for your response. I'm new to Opencart. Can you please tell me which files are supposed be updated.